# Fiat Punto Evo Sport Wing Mirror repair

Tags: fiat, wing-mirrors, punto

I would be very appreciative for some general advice here.

This morning during my commute (In the UK) I managed to park clip the driver's side wing mirror of a parked Fiat Punto. (Apparently an evo Sport.) I can confirm this detached the plastic cover. I didn't have the sense to check if the mirror cracked. Apparently it did.

A google search for the vehicle reg suggests a 2010/2011 registration.

I left a note, and I just received a call. Apparently the owner is a mechanic, and the car is a show vehicle, the mirror has a 'special' paint, and will need replacing entirely. He claimed to have consulted with another mechanic, and was quoted £350 to replace and fit the mirror. He's invited me to search for alternative parts myself, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.

£350 is significantly higher than I anticipated. I feel like I've acted in good faith so far, and would like to continue doing so, but I fear this may be an attempt to exploit the situation.

In short, I would be appreciative for advice on the following.

1. Is £350 an egregious figure? If so, what might be reasonable?
2. Do you have any examples or suggestions for a replacement mirror? Links would be appreciated.
3. Any other thoughts, suggestions or advice would be welcome.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: The passenger mirror wasn't folded, suggesting neither is automatically folding. I'm not sure if the mirror is heated or electrically adjustable, but I'd suggest assuming it is when considering an upper end estimate.

Comment: If the miorror has been painted to match the vehicle with a special paint (a "show" vehicle could have a pearlescent paint or a metal flake with several layers of lacquer etc) which is expensive to replace.

Comment: Of course, you could just complete the insurance forms and do it that way... You did hit another vehicle after all...

Comment: Rather than thinking about the cost of the mirror, think about the cost of your insurance deductible (plus increased renewal). Might be cheaper to just pay up.

Comment: £350 isn't completely over-the-top, especially if that's for the heated, electrically adjusted variety, and we're talking about OEM parts and there's some custom paint involved. A pattern part painted in one of the standard paintcodes is going to be [significantly cheaper](https://www.wingmirrorman.co.uk/wing-mirrors/fiat-wing-mirror-units/fiat-punto-evo/fiat-punto-evo-2009-2012/fiat-punto-evo-2009-2012-electric-heated-primed-wing-mirror-unit-passenger-side) but whether that's acceptable to the guy is anyone's guess. Might be worth an ask though?

Comment: It may also be worth ringing a Fiat main dealer and getting a quote - any questions surrounding "special" paint jobs aside that should give you an idea whether his quote is reasonable or extracting the Micheal

Comment: He's had a look online and found a part for £80, with another £80 for painting and fitting. I was happy to accept, and I've bought him some wine for his trouble (Hopefully he drinks!).

Solar Mike is, of course, correct. either party would have been entitled to go through insurance, but I'm happy to have avoided that route.

I consider this question closed, thank you all for the prompt, and honest advice. I'm not sure how to mark this as resolved, but I'm happy for a mod to do so.

Comment: @Charles good solution !